# why doesn't the qr code (generated with qr.make()) take me to the right URL?

Tags: google-sheets, qr-code

I am trying to generate a qr code of a google sheets file that ends with "edit#gid=1473689815". This last part of the URL is the name of a specific sheet in the file. So the problem is that when I scann the qr code with my iPhone (without a spefic qrcode leser app) the code brings me to the first sheet of the file. Do you maybe know if this part of the URL is making some trouble at the moment of the qrcodegeneration? What else should I try?
And no matter which app I use (neither generating the qrcode on google sheets itself) the qr code brings me ALWAYS to the first sheet of the file.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: just a guess - assuming all above is true it would mean that your qr.make() is not able to work with # symbol so everything after # (included) is ignored / left out

Answer (score 0):

Try to encode the url before generating the qrcode with

```
encodeURI(url)
```

[encodeURI](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it doesnt work either. I encoded it using: 
*data = 'URL ending with edit#gid=1473689815'*
*import urllib.parse*
*encoded  = urllib.parse.quote(data)* 
   *edit%23gid%3D1473689815* (that is the part above encoded)
*img = qrcode.make(encoded)*
*img.save('MyQRCode1.png')*

The qr code can be generated but after scanning it with my phone it brings me to a window in safari "file cannot be opened, check the adress and try again"
If I copy and paste the encoded URL in my browser I get the same window. 
What am I doing wrong? 
Thanks

Comment: I apologize, actually # remains as it is, and I have the same problem even if the url contains the gid with google on android.